# Can someone show me example for running a stored procedure twice and get diff results?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

For the past few weeks I have been really struggling doing something that should be really simple!

I have a stored procedure in a database which I call twice.  Each call results in totally different data. I need the entity framework to treat it like this

At the moment it caches everything

So I am going to ask for help in a different way!

Could someone show me how do this in this situation:

```
tblInvoice table
Amount Float
InvoiceDate dateTime

Invoice Data:
AccountID: 1 InvoiceDate: 12 Dec 2009 Amount: 100
AccountID: 1 InvoiceDate: 11 Dec 2009 Amount: 150
AccountID: 2 InvoiceDate: 11 Nov 2008 Amount: 150
```

Stored Procedure spGetInvoicesForDateRange - Returns all invoices for date range

1. spGetInvoicesForDateRange 01 Dec 2009 - 31 Dec 2009
2. spGetInvoicesForDateRange 01 Nov 2008 - 30 Nov 2008

At present, with my code executing 2 above would still return the results of 1 but executing 2) should only return the invoice for 11 nov 2008

My model is generated using Entity Framework but my context inherits from ObjectContext so I cant use ObjectTrackingEnabled

If someone could show me how to do the above I can then try to adapt it to my situation

Cheers

Paul

Comment: Did you use sql profiler to look what actually is called? If you use SQL Server Express Edition, you can use this one: http://anjlab.com/en/projects/opensource/sqlprofiler